# object from AJAX call is undefined on client's server only

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a web app that is running a AJAX call, that works locally, and on test servers, however, on the client end, it doesn't.

The client had the app, and then the architecture of it changed a bit, and now they say it is not working after reuploading it to their server. Unfortunately there is no way to test it manually on the server, all I have is this simple error log they gave:

```
App.jsx:63 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (App.jsx:63)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

This error log tells me the problem is the following snippet. It can't read the name variable of json.settings, since json.settings is undefined. If it is undefined that means that json at least exists, thus the AJAX call worked, meaning "settings.json" file exists and is found in the right path...

So the only thing I could do to replicate the error locally, is if settings.json doesn't even have a settings element in the object.

Looking at the files given to the client, this is not the case...

Is there something I'm overlooking?

```
$.get("settings.json")
  .done(function(json) {
    name = json.settings.name;
  }
```

Comment: No, that's what that means.  The object `json` does not have a key of `settings` in it.

Comment: try doing a console.log(json) to see the attributes of that object

Comment: so how come the settings.json on their server doesn't have that key? its literally in the file given to them, and works locally @Taplar

Comment: Obligatory ["There's no such thing as a JSON Object" link](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: I cannot tell you what the disconnect is between what the server has and what is returned to the client.  All I know is, based on that error, that's what is happening

Comment: Maybe the client didn't use the file you gave to them? I've had clients read my instructions and do something completely different "because it seemed like it would work better that way".

Comment: @HereticMonkey no that's not the case, its just a zip file for everything they upload

Comment: Oh!, lol.  I bet I know the issue.  `$.get()` does not necessarily parse the response into json, unless the content type on the response is 'application/json'.  Try using `$.getJSON()` instead.  if `json` is a string, there wouldn't be a settings property on it

Comment: so the response from the server isn't in the correct format and I need to parse it? however my server and my local is doing it already?

Comment: The client's server is not serving .json files with a Content-Type of application/json. Most web servers will, but it is something that could be configured incorrectly.

Comment: @HereticMonkey does this mean that potentially, even with getJSON() that it could still break unless their server actually is configured correctly? I thought that if the server couldn't server JSON, then the get request wouldn't even have a response, but it does

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `getJSON` will run `$.parseJSON` on whatever it receives, no matter what the server says it is, so you should be good there.

Comment: so, if after changing to getJSON() I still get a error about the response, it MUST be due to server configuration not being set up for JSON right?

Comment: have you actually double-checked what data is coming back from the server? Watch the request in your browser's network tab and see what the response is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fetching JSON, and you want to make sure that jQuery auto parses the response, you should use `$.getJSON()`

```
$.getJSON("settings.json", function(json){
  console.log(json)
});
```

`$.get()` will auto convert the response to json on two conditions.  The first being if you explicitly tell it to by giving it the data type you expect as 'json'.  The second being if you do not tell it, and the server returns the response with a Content-Type of `application/json`, in which case jQuery will try to parse it for you without you telling it to.  `$.getJSON()` is shorthand for you telling it that the response should be json and to auto parse it for you.

Ref. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Another option would be to leave it as you have it and use `JSON.parse(json)` on the response, but why type more?